# Why does "git cat-file -p HEAD^2" fail?

Tags: git, revision

"git cat-file -p HEAD^2" gives me the following error:

```
fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD^2
```

However, using the "~" format, it works:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD~2
```

[gitrevision man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) says the following:

> ... A suffix ^ to a revision parameter means
>   the first parent of that commit object. rev^n means the nth parent
>   (i.e. rev^ is equivalent to rev^1)

What have I misunderstood?

Comment: And `HEAD` has two parent commits?

Comment: I think so. "... HEAD~2" works for me. Isn't "HEAD^n" equivalent to "HEAD~n"?

Comment: @Ltf4an No. See http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References

Comment: Your link clearly explains it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a similar error message on Windows (in a CMD session, not in a git-bash session).
You need to escape the `^`, with an `^`.

```
git cat-file -p HEAD^^2
```

But that won't work unless HEAD has two parents (meaning is the result of a merge), which seems to be the case here.

For instance:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\git>gl
*   74a844a - (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'rj/mailmap-ramsay' (6 days ago) <Junio C Hamano>
|\
| * dafc047 - mailmap: update my entry with new email address (11 days ago) <Ramsay Jones>
* |   b6bd2d0 - Merge branch 'bn/send-email-smtp-auth-error-message-fix' (6 days ago) <Junio C Hamano>
```

That gives:

```
C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\git>git cat-file -p @^2
fatal: Not a valid object name @2

C:\Users\vonc\prog\git\git>git cat-file -p @^^2
tree c78343c7a98b4cb8a455d73aeecaa8acfa2cb30e
parent f4d9753a89bf04011c00e943d85211906e86a0f6
author Ramsay Jones <ramsay@ramsayjones.plus.com> 1441122606 +0100
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1442419728 -0700
```

Since your error message is  `Not a valid object name HEAD^2`, instead of  `Not a valid object name @2`, that means the HEAD has only one parent.

---

> HEAD~2" works for me. Isn't "HEAD^n" equivalent to "HEAD~n"?

No:

> `HEAD~` and `HEAD^` are equivalent.
>   The difference becomes apparent when you specify a number.
>   `HEAD~2` means “the first parent of the first parent,” or “the grandparent”

```
X--x--x
     /
    Y
```

`@~2` is `X`, while `@^2` is `Y`.

Comment: The error message wouldn't say `HEAD^2` if that were the problem.

Comment: @hvd True. I have edited the answer to make that clear.

Comment: I'm using MinGW (GNU for Windows). Escaping it fails in the same way, "fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD^^2". Also, I just tried "... HEAD^1" which works.

Comment: @Ltf4an it works on a bash, not on a cmd. I have edited my answer to address your question in the comments above.

Comment: @VonC, I now see my  misunderstanding. The notation rev^n indicates the nth parent involved in a multi-branch merge, not a parent in an ancestor chain which is what rev~n is for.